# javascript Chrome Extension Not able to read httponly cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I need to delete gmail cookies set in my chrome browser, using chrome extension , but it can delete all cookies other then Gmail cookies, then I noticed that Gmail cookies are httponly, Is there a way to remove them using javascript chrome extension..

Thanks  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one works absolutely fine for deleting every cookie, even if it is **httponly**

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({'domain':'accounts.google.com'},function(cookie){ 

    for(i=0;i<cookie.length;i++){

    var prefix = "https://";

    var url =  prefix + cookie[i].domain + cookie[i].path;

    chrome.cookies.remove({'url':url , 'name':cookie[i].name},function(cookie){ });             
    }       
 });
```

Answer (score 21):

Chrome extensions can use `chrome.cookies` API, that has access to all cookies in the cookie store, including `httpOnly`.

The documentation for the API is [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies).

Note that this API requires declaring a permission and will not work from content scripts.

Comment: Hi Xan,Thanks for your reply, I appreciate and agree with you in terms of chrome.cookies method, however I cannot access httponly cookies using it. Sorry for improper content provided.I have updated my question with code. Thanks a lot, I'll be glad if you can help

Comment: @user5821368 It seems that you have resolved your problem - it's better if you post your final solution as a separate answer, and not as part of the question.

Comment: Sure Xan, I am new to StackOverFlow..so were not much aware. Thanks btw

Comment: This answer is not clear given the comments from the OP, is it possible to access or not HTTPOnly cookies from chrome extensions nowadays ? The API doc mentions you can "set" the HttpOnly value of a cookie, is it same to assume it can do that on any cookie and such read HttpOnly cookies ?

Answer (score -9):

The point of HTTPOnly cookies is not let javascript to access them. 
So basically you can not read them.
If you want to delete them you can do it from the options that offers browser

Comment: And yet the question is specifically for a browser extension, that _has_ that level of access.

Comment: Hi Guti, Sorry I do not want to delete cookies directly from the browser I am aware about this option but I am a developer and want my code to do it for me, question is about using chrome Extention. Thanks for your reply btw :)