# Can't access httpOnly (like "set-cookie") header of a response when making request from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I'm trying to make a script that will automate something for me and my goal is to make an HTTP request and grab the "set-cookie" that is in the response's headers.

I understand why it's not accessible when done from a normal web page (httpOnly and all) but I am doing it from the background script in a chrome extension.

I tried using both fetch and xhr but they both didn't show me the set-cookie header in the response.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log("headers", xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); // doesnt return httpOnly headers
  }
};
xhr.open("GET", 'https://' + host, true);
xhr.send();
```

or

```
fetch('https://' + host, {method: 'GET'})
```

Is there any way to get permission to read those headers? Maybe I need to use something other than fetch? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993526/javascript-chrome-extension-not-able-to-read-httponly-cookies - that shows how to access such cookies, but not from an arbitrary request on a different domain - maybe there's something in that page though, just posted in case

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, I do know of that method but my intent of reading these cookies is so i can generate multiple sessions for myself, save them in localStorage of my extension (and alternate between them later on as i want) so I can't really use this method. Thank you so much for answering though! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can read them in webRequest.onHeadersReceived if it's registered with 'extraHeaders'.